# help with wired internet connection

Tags: 18.04, internet, connection, wired

I have been back and forth from windows 4 times now, having tried over and over to get the internet to work.

For some reason Ubuntu is not picking up anything from my router automatically. I tried every release available, ending with Ubuntu 18.04  Bionic Beaver, and while that loaded nicer it still was incomplete and unable to network. It also failed to read the disc for my motherboard or open it, to get the ethernet adapter driver that way was impossible.

Windstream, my ISP, says its not a router issue, its a software issue, and Windows still works like normal so I dont know why its not cooperating in a similar manner.

`sudo ip addr` and `sudo lshw -c network` outputs:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You appear to be operating under the misconception that the Windows drivers supplied on disk from your motherboard manufacturer are useful for an Ubuntu installation. Boot from the installer, select "Try Ubuntu", open a terminal and issue the command `sudo lshw -C network` and copy and [edit] the output into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: In a recent Ubuntu version, what does `sudo ip addr` give you?

Comment: 1: lo:  <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000

Comment: link/loopback bunch of 0s

Comment: also, on start of load it says no irq handler for vector

Comment: i guess if you click the thing says enter image description here thats a screenshot now

Comment: some of the forums other than here reference this as a motherboard issue, and have a grub loader script change or something of that nature to fix...

Comment: my particular motherboard is an asrock